# rails server successfully, but can't access in mobile

Tags: mobile

Iam able to access rails app in all systems with in network, but unable to access in mobiles.

I started app like below

rails s -b ip

Answer (score 0):

Double check if your mobile is in the same network of your server. You can do this either by pinging your mobile device (if it support ping) or doing a network scan using tools like nmap or take a look at your router to see where is your device.  If you want to allow all access, the binding ip should be 0.0.0.0.

Comment: both devises in same network but i dont understand why its not access, any how, I installed ngrok and access the app in mobile devise.  Great thanks for your reply